# Writing sections for the proposed guide to be more inclusive of Japanese speakers

Tags: discussion

As a follow up to [Creating as much Japanese interface as possible to be more inclusive of native Japanese speakers](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/608/), I thought it might pay to try to start writing some sections of the guide which might be relevant to Japanese users of this site so that it can be combined later.

Answer (score 5):

The goal of this isn't to explain every way of doing things, it's just to give a general functional overview of how to use it, explaining only the bits which are the most relevant to this site.

The Markdown editing system used on this site is often not well understood by native speakers of both English and Japanese, so I think it's on the priority list if a guide is to be written. If you see anything you'd like to add/change etc, feel free to edit this.

## 質問や回答の書き方

下記に示す書式にしたがって、質問や回答を記入してください。

- 改行は`<br/>`で表す:

  ```
  apples, pears<br/>oranges
  ```

  apples, pears
  oranges
- フォントスタイルを変更する:

  ```
  *italics*, **bold** and ***bold italics***
  ```

  *italics*, **bold** and ***bold italics***

  日本語に対しては、`*`によるマークアップがバグで機能しないため、`<b></b>`や`<i></i>`を使う:

  ```
  <b>公園</b>には<i>桜</i>が<b><i>咲いています</i></b>。
  ```

  **公園**には*桜*が***咲いています***。
- ウェブサイトにリンクする:

  ```
  [Google](http://www.google.com/) or http://www.google.com
  ```

  [Google](http://www.google.com/) or http://www.google.com
- 引用文は、すべての行頭に`>`を一つ入れる:

  ```
  > うわあ、すごい！<br/>
  > Wow, that's great!
  ```

  > うわあ、すごい！
  >   Wow, that's great!
- 非順序リストを追加する:

  ```
  * Item 1
  * Item 2
  * Item 3
  ```

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3
- 順序リストを追加する:

  ```
  1. Apples
  2. Pears
  3. Oranges
  ```

  1. Apples
  2. Pears
  3. Oranges
- "順序リスト"や"非順序リスト"内の各行は、文頭に4つの空白文字を入れる:

  ```
  * The example sentence is as follows:
      > うわあ、すごい！
      
      the translation of which is:
      
      > Wow, that's great!
  ```

  - The example sentence is as follows:

    > うわあ、すごい!

    the translation of which is:

    > Wow, that's great!
- 日本語は、バックチック(`` ` ``)でくくり、日本語の背景色を灰色にする:

  ```
  The word `千里眼` refers to "clairvoyance".
  ```

  The word `千里眼` refers to "clairvoyance".
- ふりがなは、`[漢字]​{かな}`フォーマットで表す:

  ```
  [一]​{いち}[月]​{がつ}, [明後日]{あさって}
  ```

  [一]{いち}[月]{がつ}, [明後日]{あさって}

Comment: Why did you put square brackets around the kanji in the last example? So far as I know, it's not needed. Does it add some additional benefit?

Comment: @DaveMG It's usually not needed, but I didn't want to have to explain about [this bug](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/559/feature-bugfix-request-for-furigana) so I thought I'd only show the syntax which works all the time.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with this. Are we supposed to make a Japanese version for it?

Comment: @Flaw I've tried to translate the above to Japanese. I wrote it first in English just to get started.

Comment: This is amazing stuff, guys! I was worried that after I suggested this happen that I wouldn't be able to get around to starting it, but I just checked in on Meta now and saw all this work you guys were doing. Fantastic! (I still feel a but lame for not contributing more... ) This will be a huge help to Japanese speakers, as well as being a great resource for when SE one day (hopefully) supports true localization! Can't commend you guys enough on this.

Answer (score 3):

### 用語集

[元ネタ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)から削除改変。

#### 2k User / 2kユーザー

> →Editor

#### 3k User / 3kユーザー

> →Closer

#### 10ker, 10k User, 10k Tools / 10kユーザー、10kツール

> 名声が10,000を超えたユーザーのこと。[管理ツール](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-facilities-are-there-in-the-moderation-tools)が解禁され、モデレーター向けレポートや通知を見ることができるが、モデレーターレベルの操作の多くは運営から指定されたモデレーター (♦ ダイヤモデレーター) に限定されている。にもかかわらず10kユーザーも「モデレーター」と呼ばれることがある。

#### Accept Rate / 承認率

> 投稿した質問のうち、解決 (回答を承認) 済みのものが何パーセントあるか。これにカウントされない質問や、この数字自体が表示されない場合もある (詳しくは[公式ブログの記事](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/)を参照)。

#### Accepted Answer / 承認された回答、ベストアンサー

> 質問者によって選ばれた、「一番役に立った」回答。ベストアンサーには緑のチェックマークが表示される。賞金付きだった場合は緑のチェックマークに黄色の縁取りがついたものになる。ほとんどの場合、ベストアンサーは回答リストの一番目に表示される。
>
> →[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/)

#### API

> すべてのStack Exchangeサイトで利用できる公開APIのこと。これを通して、質問・回答・コメント・ユーザー情報にアクセスすることができる。詳しくは[StackApps](http://stackapps.com)にドキュメントがある。

#### Atwood

> →Jeff Atwood

#### Badges / バッジ

> Stack Exchangeサイトに作り込まれている報奨システムのいち要素。名声は投票のしくみを通して獲得するが、バッジはその他のサイトへの貢献・実績・行動へのごほうびとなっている。(一つ一つのバッジの詳細については[バッジ一覧](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/badges)に解説がある。)
>
> →[How do “Badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

#### Ban, Suspension / バン、アカウント停止

> →penalty box

#### Bounty / 賞金

> 質問につけることができる一定量の名声値で、質問者が正しい回答を選んだ時点で、その回答者に与えられる。この仕組みを使うことで、名声値は少し消費するものの、7日間[Featuredタブ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured)内に質問が掲載されるようになり、質問を目立たせることができる。

#### CAPTCHA

> [ボット](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%83%88)に編集などされないように防止する仕組み。極端に連続して早い編集など、普通のユーザーによる操作がシステムに誤認され、CAPTCHA画面が表示されることがある。
>
> 例: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/captcha

#### Close, Closed / 閉じる、閉じられた質問

> もうそれ以上回答を投稿できない質問。名声が3,000以上あるユーザーは、何らかの理由で質問がこのサイトにそぐわないと判断した場合、その質問の閉鎖に1票を入れることができる。これが5票に達すると、質問は閉鎖される。各質問につき1人のユーザーが投票できるのは1回までになっている。
>
> →Reopen

#### Closer / クローザー

> 名声が3,000以上あるユーザーのこと。FAQに記載されている基準に従って、質問を閉じるかについて投票することができる。

#### Comments / コメント

> 質問でも回答でもないようなことは、コメント欄でやりとりすることができる。(投稿者に不明な箇所について質問したいときなど)

#### Community Wiki / コミュニティウィキ

> 名声が100以上あるユーザーなら誰でも編集できるようになっている質問や回答。CWな質問や回答に投票しても名声が増減することはない。

#### Creative Commons Data Dump / クリエイティブ・コモンズ・データダンプ

> トリロジーサイト・Stack Exchangeネットワークサイトのうち本サービスに入っているものについて、CC BY-SAライセンスのデータを書き出したもので、公式から定期的に提供される。これには投稿・コメント・投票・バッジ・ユーザー情報 (個人が特定できる情報は削除されている) が含まれる。公式ブログの該当カテゴリはこちら: [Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)

### Creative Commons License / クリエイティブ・コモンズ・ライセンス

> ユーザーの投稿・コメントなどすべてに付与されるライセンス。[詳しくは公式ブログ記事を参照。](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/now-licensed-under-creative-commons/)

### CW

> →Community Wiki

#### Data Dump / データダンプ

> →Creative Commons Data Dump

#### Delete, Deleted / 削除する、削除された質問・回答

> 質問や回答はモデレーターによって削除されたり、10,000以上名声のあるユーザーからの投票によって削除されたりする場合がある。モデレーターや10kユーザーは、削除された投稿も見ることができる。

#### Diamond Mod[erator] / ダイヤモンドモデレーター

> →Moderator

#### Dupe, Duplicate / 重複

> 以前投稿された質問と同じ内容の質問。質問の重複はSEサイトではよくないものとされている — 理想としては、問題・疑問への正解は1つの質問を見ればわかるようになっているべきである。3,000以上名声があるユーザーは、質問が重複しているとして閉鎖に1票を入れることができる。

#### Editor / エディター

> 2,000以上名声があるユーザー。凍結されていない投稿であれば、コミュニティウィキでなくても編集することができる。

#### Edit War / 編集合戦

> 2人以上のユーザーが際限なく編集したり、差し戻したりしている状態。モデレーターが投稿を凍結する理由の1つである。

#### FAQ

> Frequently Asked Questionsの略。「よくある質問」
>
> 大抵はサイト上部のメニューにリンクがある[faq](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/faq)ページのことだが、メタサイトの投稿で、モデレーター専用タグ[[faq]](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)が付けられたものも言う。また、「[公式FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)」はコミュニティ全体によって編集管理されているポストで、SEサイトの機能や動作の解説を一箇所に集約しようとしている。

#### Favorites / お気に入り(の質問)

> 各質問の投票ボタンの下にある([image: 星マーク])をクリックすることで、質問をブックマークすることができる。お気に入りの質問は自分のユーザープロフィールで一覧を見ることができる。

#### Favorite Tags / お気に入りタグ

> タグをお気に入りタグとして登録することで、質問一覧でそのタグが付いた質問をより目立つ色で表示させることができる。
>
> 旧称はInteresting tag

#### Flags / 通報

> 悪意ある投稿、スパムな投稿など、どうしようもない投稿があった場合、モデレーターに通報することができる。2日の間に6つ通報があった投稿は自動的に削除される。
>
> 自分ではどうすることもできない問題がある場合にはモデレーターに通報しよう。

#### Flair / フレア、缶バッジ?

> ユーザー一人一人のバナーのこと。ユーザー名と名声、バッジ数、アイコンがコンパクトに表示される。質問や回答の投稿者を表示する時に使われる他、外部のウェブサイトに設置して、Stack Exchangeサイトのメンバーであることの印として使うことができる。flairという呼び方は1999年の映画 [リストラ・マン](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BB%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3) から ([Stack Overflowポッドキャスト、エピソード54](http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode54-2009.05.20.mp3)の5分48秒を参照)。
>
> →[Now Earn Valuable Flair!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/nowearn-valuable-flair/)
>
> 例: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/flair/2

#### Gravatar / グラバター

> このサービスにプロフィールアイコンを登録すると、色々なサイトで表示できるようになる。globally recognized avatarの略。

#### Ignored Tags / 無視するタグ

> タグを無視するタグに登録すると、質問一覧でそのタグが付いた質問はより目立たない色で表示されるようになる。設定を変更することで、全く表示しないようにすることもできる。

#### JLU

> 本サイトの名前、Japanese Language & Usageの略。

#### Jeff Atwood / ジェフ・アトウッド

> SEサイトを運営するStack Overflow Internet Services, inc.の共同設立者。

#### Joel Spolsky / ジョエル・スポルスキ

> SEサイトを運営するStack Overflow Internet Services, inc.の共同設立者。

#### Locked / ロック、凍結

> モデレーターは投稿を「ロック」することができ、その場合投稿を編集・投票・コメントを追加・閉鎖・リオープンすることはできなくなる。ロックされた質問でも (閉鎖されていなければ) 回答を追加することはできる。また (ロックされていない) 回答についても編集・投票することができる。
>
> →[What is a “Locked” question? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-question-how-do-they-work)

#### Markdown / マークダウン

> 投稿を書くときに使われる記法。[Wikipedia記事](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)、[リファレンス](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/editing-help)。

#### Merge / マージ

> 重複質問は最終的に閉じられることがほとんどだが、モデレーターによって重複質問への回答が元からあった質問にコピーされることがある。この時、重複質問は同時に削除される。元からあった質問への回答は、もともと付いていた回答と、重複質問から来た回答の両方を合わせたものになる。

#### Meta / メタ

> Q&Aサイト自体に関するサポート、機能要望、相談を取り扱うために設置されているサポートサイト (このサイト) のこと。

#### Migration / 移動

> 他のSEサイトの方がふさわしいと判断された質問については、質問内容と回答が移動先のサイトにコピーされ、元のサイトの質問は閉じられる。移動するには5人のユーザーが"Belongs on [移動先のサイト]"として閉鎖投票をする必要がある。

#### Moderator / モデレーター

> コミュニティの世話役として任じられた一般ユーザー。一般ユーザーにはない権限が与えられており、質問をマージしたり、タグを一括操作したりといった権力をもてあそぶことができる。名前の後に ♦ がついているかどうかで区別できる。

#### MSO

> Stack OverflowのメタQ&Aサイト。Stack Exchangeネットワークに含まれるサイト全体に関わるQ&A、バグ報告、機能要望も取り扱う。

#### Off-topic / オフトピック

> Stack Exchangeネットワークのサイトで扱う質問の範囲を外れていると思われる質問を指す。

#### OP

> Original Posterの略。「大元の投稿者」。質問を投稿した人、を端的に言いたい場合に使う。

#### OT

> →off-topic.

#### OpenID / OpenID

> SEサイトにログインする方法の1つ。ユーザー名とパスワードを一組登録しておくだけで、[OpenID](http://openid.net/)が有効なサイトであればどこでもログインすることができる仕組み。

#### Penalty Box / ペナルティーボックス

> 一般には、アイスホッケーで一時退場を命じられた選手が待機するスペース。
>
> [ユーザーの行動がサイトに悪影響を与えている](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)、とモデレーターによって判断された場合、アカウント停止措置がとられることがある。「ペナルティボックス」に入っている間、質問・回答を投稿することはできず、停止期間が終了するまで名声は1に固定される。

#### Post / ポスト、投稿

> 質問と回答を区別せずにいうときの呼び方。

#### Preferences, Prefs / 設定

> ユーザーごとにカスタマイズ可能な設定。お気に入りのタグ、無視するタグ、無視するタグのついた質問を完全に隠すかどうか、投稿した質問・回答に反応があったらメールで通知するかどうか、など。

#### Profile / プロフィール

> 各ユーザーについてサイトでの活動状況をまとめたもの。例: [ジェフ・アトウッドのプロフィール](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)

#### Recalc

> →Reputation Recalculation

#### ReCAPTCHA / ReCAPTCHA

> CAPTCHAを実現するために裏で使われているサービスの名前。
>
> →CAPTCHA

#### Reopen / リオープン

> 3,000以上名声があるユーザーは、閉じられた質問を「元に戻す」と投票することができる。5票集まれば質問はリオープンされ、回答を追加することができるようになる。ユーザー一人あたりについて投票できるのは1回だけである。
>
> →Close

#### Reputation, Rep / 名声

> 「名声」はユーザーが獲得した *得点* で、どのくらいサイトに貢献したかの目安となる。ユーザーの投稿に他のユーザーが投票することで、名声が増減する。一定量の名声を獲得すると、できることが増えたり、名声の低いユーザーには使えないような管理機能にアクセスしたりすることができるようになる。
>
> →[How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

#### Reputation Cap, Rep Cap / 名声獲得限度

> 1日あたりに獲得できる名声は200までとなっている。ただし、回答が承認された時に入ってくる名声についてはこの限度は適用されない。

#### Reputation Recalculation, Rep Recalc / 名声の再計算

> モデレーターおよび[ユーザー自身](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/self-instigated-rep-recalc)の手によって、名声をデータベースの内容に沿って「再計算」させることができる。例えば投稿を削除しても、名声にすぐ反映されるわけではない。「名声の再計算」によって、投稿や投票の最新の状態を名声に反映させることができる。

#### Revision History / 編集履歴

> 質問や回答に加えられた全ての変更の詳細。"edited [日付]"というリンクをクリックすると見ることができる。
>
> URLは`http://{サイト}/posts/{投稿ID}/revisions`のようになる。

#### Rollback / 差し戻す

> 質問の編集画面に入り、編集履歴から以前のバージョンを選択、その内容を最新版として質問に反映するという一連の操作。結果的に選択されたバージョン以降の編集内容は差し戻される。編集履歴にはすべて残っている。

#### Score / スコア

> 投票数から減点投票数を引いたもの。

#### SE

> →Stack Exchange

#### SEI

> Stack Exchange, Inc.の略。運営会社。SE (StackExchange、Q&Aサイトのネットワーク) と言うべきところで誤ってSEIとしている場合がよくみられる。

#### Sock Puppet, Sock Puppet Account / 自作自演、自作自演アカウント

> 本当のアカウントではできないことを実行するために作られた重複アカウント。例えば票を水増しする、自分の投稿に票をいれる、など、本来禁止されていたりマナーに反したりするような行為。
>
> →Voter Fraud

#### SOFU, S[OFU], S[O|F|U]

> Stack Overflow,、Server Fault、Super Userの略。「Stack Overflowトリロジー」の一番よく使われる定義に含まれるサイトである。Stack Overflowはプログラミング、Server Faultはシスアド、Super Userはパソコンユーザー向けのQ&Aサイト。
>   →Trilogy

#### Spam / スパム

> 宣伝目的の投稿。真面目に質問したり回答したりする気のないもの。

#### Spolsky

> →Joel Spolsky

#### Stack Exchange

> さまざまなトピックごとに設置されたQ&Aサイトのネットワークで、このサイトもその一つ。Stack Overflow Internet Servicesによって運営されており、現在のバージョン、Stack Exchange 2.0はコミュニティによる自治を特徴とする。以前のバージョンStack Exchange 1.0は個人向け有料サービスで、Stack OverflowのエンジンをベースにしたQ&Aサイトのホスティングサービスだったが、現在は終了している。詳しくはhttp://stackexchange.com へ。

#### Status Tags / ステータスタグ

> メタサイトでは、モデレーターしか使えないタグが幾つかあり、区別がつくように赤く表示されるようになっている。これらのモデレーター専用タグは、機能要望やバグ報告に対して開発チームから公式のステータス報告ができるようにと導入されたものである。[複数の意味合い](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37825/what-is-a-bad-feature-of-stack-overflow/37832#37832)を持つタグもあるので注意されたい。
>
> [ステータスタグのついた質問一覧](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-~)
>
> 例: [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

#### Tags / タグ

> 投稿者が質問につけたラベル。同じタグのついた質問をまとめて見ることができる。きちんとタグ付けすることで、他の人が質問を見つけやすくなり、ひいては回答をもらいやすくなる。

#### The Team / ザ・チーム

> Stack Overflow開発チームのこと。連絡は team@stackoverflow.com まで。

#### Trilogy (三部作)

> Stack Overflow (すたっくおーばーふろー), Server Fault (さーばーふぉーると), Super User (すーぱーゆーざー)の3つが、「Stack Overflowトリロジー」に含まれるサイトである。
>   以下を指すこともある:
>   - SO/SF/MSOのみ
>   - SOFU + MSOのみ
>   - Stack Exchangeネットワークに含まれる全てのサイト、およびArea 51、Careers、StackApps

#### Views / 閲覧数

> 質問やユーザープロフィールにアクセスした人の数。

#### Vote[r] Fraud / 投票(者)詐欺

> 不審な投票パターン。同一人物が複数のアカウントを駆使していることが多い。復讐心から減点投票を繰り返すことも言う。[公式ブログ記事も参照。](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/)
>
> →Sock Puppet Accounts

#### Voting / 投票する

> 質問や回答の左側にある上向きの矢印をクリックすることで投票 upvote できる。この時同時に投稿者に名声が10入る。下向きの矢印をクリックすると減点投票 downvote になる。この時ウィキではない投稿では、投稿者の名声が2減り、投票者の名声が1減る。

#### Wiki / ウィキ

> →Community Wiki

Comment: A quick note: original credit to this post goes to [ento](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/users/128/ento) :) At the time of this comment, it's displayed as "unknown" because of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230512. (BTW @ento, if you read this, see also http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1200 where this was referenced)

Answer (score 2):

Below is an auto-generated list (as of 27/1/2012) of the tags which have more than 1 tagged question from the JLU localization script, sorted from the most to least number of tags. I hope it's useful:

## タグリスト

[`文法` <sup>grammar (300)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), [`言葉選び` <sup>word-choice (274)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice), [`言葉使い` <sup>usage (163)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage), [`ニュアンス` <sup>nuances (109)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuances), [`翻訳` <sup>translation (105)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation), [`語彙` <sup>vocabulary (98)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary), [`不変化詞` <sup>particles (92)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particles), [`言葉` <sup>words (92)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words), [`漢字` <sup>kanji (88)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kanji), [`動詞` <sup>verbs (85)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs), [`意味` <sup>meaning (80)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning), [`語源` <sup>etymology (60)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology), [`動詞の活用` <sup>conjugations (52)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjugations), [`丁寧さ` <sup>politeness (47)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politeness), [`発音` <sup>pronunciation (43)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation), [`俗語` <sup>slang (42)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slang), [`決まり文句` <sup>set-phrases (41)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-phrases), [`同義語` <sup>synonyms (40)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonyms), [`定義` <sup>definitions (39)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definitions), [`読み` <sup>readings (37)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/readings), [`文化` <sup>culture (35)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture), [`数字` <sup>numbers (33)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numbers), [`て形` <sup>te-form (32)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/te-form), [`固有名詞` <sup>formal-noun (32)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-noun), [`学び` <sup>learning (31)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), [`助詞「に」` <sup>particle-ni (31)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-ni), [`口語` <sup>colloquial (30)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colloquial), [`方言` <sup>dialects (28)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialects), [`歴史` <sup>history (28)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), [`日本語能力試験` <sup>jlpt (27)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jlpt), [`参考文献` <sup>resources (27)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources), [`表現` <sup>expression (27)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression), [`形容詞` <sup>adjectives (26)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjectives), [`外来語` <sup>loanwords (24)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loanwords), [`縮約` <sup>contractions (23)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contractions), [`ビジネス日本語` <sup>business-japanese (22)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-japanese), [`敬語` <sup>honorifics (22)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/honorifics), [`イディオム` <sup>idioms (22)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms), [`構文` <sup>syntax (20)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax), [`敬語` <sup>keigo (18)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keigo), [`正字法` <sup>orthography (18)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography), [`スペリング` <sup>spelling (18)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling), [`助詞「の」` <sup>particle-no (18)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-no), [`否定形` <sup>negative-forms (17)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negative-forms), [`専門用語` <sup>terminology (16)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology), [`話` <sup>speaking (16)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking), [`かな` <sup>kana (16)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kana), [`助詞「が」` <sup>particle-ga (16)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-ga), [`助詞「で」` <sup>particle-de (15)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-de), [`助数詞` <sup>counter-words (15)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counter-words), [`ひらがな` <sup>hiragana (15)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiragana), [`挨拶` <sup>greetings (15)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greetings), [`タイプミス` <sup>typo (15)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typo), [`接尾辞` <sup>suffixes (14)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suffixes), [`食べ物` <sup>food (14)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food), [`日常` <sup>practical (14)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practical), [`音韻論` <sup>phonology (14)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology), [`カタカナ` <sup>katakana (14)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/katakana), [`歌詞` <sup>song-lyric (14)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-lyric), [`時制` <sup>tense (13)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tense), [`形容詞` <sup>i-adjectives (13)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i-adjectives), [`用語要求` <sup>phrase-requests (13)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests), [`助詞「と」` <sup>particle-to (12)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-to), [`助詞「は」` <sup>particle-wa (12)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-wa), [`副詞` <sup>adverbs (12)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adverbs), [`接続詞` <sup>conjunctions (11)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjunctions), [`助詞「を」` <sup>particle-wo (11)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-wo), [`ニュアンス` <sup>nuance (11)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuance), [`複合語` <sup>compounds (10)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compounds), [`辞書` <sup>dictionary (10)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary), [`見方` <sup>perspective (10)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perspective), [`連結詞` <sup>copula (10)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copula), [`インターネット俗語` <sup>internet-slang (10)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-slang), [`言い回し` <sup>phrase (10)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase), [`代名詞` <sup>pronouns (10)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronouns), [`自動詞` <sup>intransitive (9)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intransitive), [`コンピュータ用語` <sup>computing (9)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computing), [`省略` <sup>ellipsis (9)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ellipsis), [`駄じゃれ` <sup>puns (9)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puns), [`引用` <sup>quotes (9)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quotes), [`擬音語` <sup>onomatopoeia (8)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onomatopoeia), [`他動詞` <sup>transitive (8)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transitive), [`違い` <sup>differences (8)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences), [`質問` <sup>questions (7)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/questions), [`可能形` <sup>potential-form (7)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potential-form), [`当て字` <sup>ateji (7)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ateji), [`ローマ字` <sup>romaji (7)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romaji), [`形式` <sup>formality (6)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formality), [`中国語` <sup>chinese (6)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese), [`受動態` <sup>passive (6)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive), [`隠喩` <sup>metaphor (6)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metaphor), [`形容動詞` <sup>na-adjectives (6)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/na-adjectives), [`名前` <sup>name (6)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/name), [`時間` <sup>time (6)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time), [`和製英語` <sup>wasei-eigo (5)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wasei-eigo), [`印刷` <sup>publishing (5)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing), [`句読点` <sup>punctuation (5)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation), [`変体仮名` <sup>obsolete-kana (5)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obsolete-kana), [`間投詞` <sup>interjections (5)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interjections), [`かなの使い` <sup>kana-usage (5)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kana-usage), [`助詞「な」` <sup>particle-na (5)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-na), [`短縮` <sup>abbreviations (5)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abbreviations), [`死語` <sup>archaic (5)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaic), [`形成` <sup>formation (5)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formation), [`高低アクセント` <sup>pitch-accent (5)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pitch-accent), [`数学` <sup>mathematics (5)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics), [`同音異義語` <sup>homonyms (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homonyms), [`美化語` <sup>bikago (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bikago), [`指示詞` <sup>demonstratives (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demonstratives), [`品詞` <sup>part-of-speech (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/part-of-speech), [`送り仮名` <sup>okurigana (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/okurigana), [`助詞「か」` <sup>particle-ka (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-ka), [`イントネーション` <sup>intonation (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intonation), [`言語学` <sup>linguistics (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics), [`関係詞節` <sup>relative-clause (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relative-clause), [`ウェブサイト` <sup>website (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website), [`動物` <sup>animals (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals), [`アニメ` <sup>anime (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime), [`不快な言葉` <sup>offensive-words (4)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive-words), [`筆順` <sup>stroke-order (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stroke-order), [`尊敬` <sup>respect (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/respect), [`部首` <sup>radicals (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radicals), [`単独言葉要求` <sup>single-word-requests (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests), [`言語変化` <sup>language-change (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-change), [`言語改革` <sup>language-reform (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-reform), [`名詞` <sup>nouns (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns), [`助詞「へ」` <sup>particle-e (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-e), [`複数` <sup>plurals (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plurals), [`音声学` <sup>phonetics (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonetics), [`使役` <sup>causative (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/causative), [`入力方式` <sup>input-method (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input-method), [`電子メール` <sup>email (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email), [`主語` <sup>subject (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subject), [`意志動詞` <sup>volitional (3)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volitional), [`助詞「より」` <sup>particle-yori (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/particle-yori), [`機械翻訳` <sup>machine-translation (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-translation), [`記憶を助けるもの` <sup>mnemonics (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mnemonics), [`方向` <sup>direction (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/direction), [`動物相` <sup>fauna (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fauna), [`民間伝承` <sup>folklore (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folklore), [`アルファベット順` <sup>alphabetical-order (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alphabetical-order), [`曖昧さ` <sup>ambiguity (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambiguity), [`理解` <sup>comprehension (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comprehension), [`色` <sup>colours (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/colours), [`付加疑問` <sup>tag-question (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-question), [`連濁` <sup>rendaku (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendaku), [`母音` <sup>vowels (2)</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vowels)