# Japanese language interface option for Japanese.SE

Tags: feature-request

In the past, we've discussed the possibility of a localized interface for Japanese.SE:

- [Is JLU an English-centric site? & Is it possible to create a localized JLU for Japanese?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/454/is-jlu-an-english-centric-site-is-it-possible-to-create-a-localized-jlu-for-j)
- [Creating as much Japanese interface as possible to be more inclusive of native Japanese speakers](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/608/creating-as-much-japanese-interface-as-possible-to-be-more-inclusive-of-native-j)
- [Localization: The state of the nation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82176) (Meta.SE)

But things have changed since then.  Japanese Stack Overflow now exists, and its interface has been translated into Japanese.  **Why not allow the Japanese interface here, too, as an official option?**

This would help us [encourage participation from native Japanese speakers](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/encouraging-participation-from-native-japanese-speakers-translating-posts).

Comment: Also a popular request at [French](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/530).